# Why do I get an "invalid syntax" error for this simple if-else code?

Tags: python

I have a simple python code as follows:

```
a = 3

if a == 3:
  print("a is 3")

print("yes")

else:
  print("a is not 3")
```

I get an invalid syntax error for the else: part. Can someone please explain why? Is it illegal to have code between an if and else statement?

Comment: Hi, thanks for clarifying. I have a follow up question. Does "try" and "except" work like "if" and "else"? As in, do they have the same indenting and de-indenting rules?

Comment: See the same page I already linked to. Or just try it!

Comment: Hi, I did go through the page but I am new to the language and didn't quite understand what was written there.

Comment: Head for the tutorial then https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is expressly forbidden](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) by the language definition. You cannot have an `else` without a matching `if`.

Note the syntax here is that you can have zero or more `elif` statements and `else` is entirely optional, if you don't want to include it.

```
if_stmt ::=  "if" assignment_expression ":" suite
             ("elif" assignment_expression ":" suite)*
             ["else" ":" suite]
```

Depending on your actual *goals* here, you could do something where you just keep the `print` function call inside of the positive `if` block instead.

```
a = 3

if a == 3:
  print("a is 3")
  print("yes")
else:
  print("a is not 3")
```

...but this is obviated by "a is 3" being printed out in advance of this, so having this `print("yes")` expression doesn't add a whole lot of extra value.

Answer (score -2):

You exited the **if** block when you printed the word "yes" because that **print** statement is indented at the same level as the **if** statement. So, when the parser finds an **else** statement on the following line, it does not have a corresponding **if** statement and raises a syntax error. It looks like you intended to indent the second **print** statement to the same level as the first one. That will certainly resolve the error anyway.

Comment: If it's indented it's not _between_ `if` and `else`, it's just in the `if` block. As the syntax error tells them, it _is_ illegal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).